# Error SQL ALTER TABLE #1064

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an error in my SQL syntax, can anyone help me please beacause I really don't see the error...

Here is the request SQL :

```
ALTER TABLE t_personne Change email_personne to mail_pers ;
```

**MySQL error**

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'to mail_pers' at line 1

please help

Comment: Have you checked the manual for alter table syntax? What are you trying to do?

Comment: You don't need the word "to", and you need to include the datatype. e.g.  `ALTER TABLE t_personne CHANGE email_personne mail_pers  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0):

SQL ALTER TABLE Syntax
To add a column in a table, use the following syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype
```

To delete a column in a table, use the following syntax (notice that some database systems don't allow deleting a column):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
DROP COLUMN column_name
```

To change the data type of a column in a table, use the following syntax:

SQL Server / MS Access:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to rename the column, Then

**Query**

```
ALTER TABLE t_personne  
CHANGE COLUMN email_personne mail_pers VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
```

[**Documentation**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)